# Find a function where $f(2, 1) = 8$ and $\nabla f(2,1)=(-1, 5/3)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm having problem finding a function $f(x, y)$ where $f(2, 1) = 8$ and $\nabla f(2, 1) = (-1, 5/3)$. How do I reverse engineer a function using its gradient?

Comment: $f(x,y) = a x + by + c$ seems like a good first attempt. The gradient tells you that $f(x,y) = -x + 5y/3 + c$, you should then be able to find $c$.

Comment: @Gregory I don't think that would be true. We are only given information bout the value of the gradient at $(2,1)$. So we can't integrate it to find the actual function. I don't think it is possible to reverse engineer the function from the gradient value at a single point. Because there would exist many such functions.

Comment: $c=\frac{25}{3}$

Comment: @VSSChaitanyaChavali As I understand the question, the asker is simply looking for a single example of a function satisfying these conditions, and finding a plane with these properties is a sensible approach. Certainly this plane is not the only function satisfying these conditions, but it is an example of such a function.